# DevTools of Google Chrome. Hide all HTTP requests with 200 status in the Network tab

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to hide all HTTP requests with 200 status in the Network tab of DevTools in Google Chrome?

I want to control broken or problem requests while doing some modifications in Web sites.

The DevTools Network tab looks pretty well to have such filtering in place.

Comment: `status-code:200 scheme:http`, more info in [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#filter).

Comment: @BitcoinMurderousManiac yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can type `-status-code:200` (notice the `-`) to give you the requests **not** with status code 200. The `-` negates the expression. For reference documentation on the filter you can check [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#filter) and also read this [tutorial](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-use-the-devtools-network-filter-effectively).

Comment: In my native language "filtering" means "filtering out", i.e. "hide". Sorry for this typo. I've updated my question to express exactly what I mean.

Comment: @it3xl I've edited the answer to do what you want. Cheers and happy coding!

Comment: Javier please return references to the documentation and those tutorial. It was pretty useful )) For reference documentation on it you can check [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#filter) and also read this [tutorial](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-use-the-devtools-network-filter-effectively).

Comment: @it3xl Thanks for the reminder, already added them back again.